# DDWRT or similar as repeater in a network

Tags: wifi, repeater

I have a friend with sever connection issues due to her wireless router being on the bottom floor of her house, and the computer being a story or two away.  I have several old Linksys routers lying about, one of which is currently running DDWRT for my network.  Would it be a good idea (effective) to configure one of these routers as a wireless bridge of some kind in an intermediary floor to improve her connection?  Is there any specific configuration beyond the standard DDWRT setup that I would need to do?

Thanks for your help. =)

Answer (score 1):

Set the routers up for [WDS](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WDS_Linked_router_network)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion WDS sucks because if its working with WPA or WPA2 its too slow.

I used the "Repeater Bridge" Mode of DDWRT and it worked fine for me.
Information can be found here: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge

Comment: I'm confused about their instructions.
It doesn't say how to enter the primary router's SSID/credential to allow the secondary router to access it wirelessly. There's only the "Wireless Security" tab, which as I understand, the SSID/credential of the secondary router.